# How to make flex item stick to its sibling vertically (without grouping)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three flex items with the following markup:

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="red">red</div>
  <div id="green">green</div>
  <div id="blue">blue</div>
</div>
```

and somewhat peculiar ordering:

```css
.container { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap }

#red { background: red; height: 500px }
#green { background: green; height: 200px }
#blue { background: blue; height: 100px }

/* mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
  #red, #green, #blue { width: 100% }
  #red, #blue { order: 1 }
}

/* desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  #red { width: 33.33333% }
  #green, #blue { width: 66.66666% }
}
```

Here's a [link to JSBin](https://jsbin.com/xatevajoji/edit?html,css,output) for preview.

This works perfectly on mobile:

```
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
| green |
|_______|
|       |
| red   |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|_______|
| blue  |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

But on desktop I get the following:

```
|‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
| red | green     |
|     |___________|
|     |
|     |
|     |
|_____|_____
| blue      |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

Whereas what I'm trying to get is:

```
|‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
| red | green     |
|     |___________|
|     | blue      |
|     |‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
|     |
|_____|
```

In other words, I'm looking for a way to move the `blue` item up to its `green` sibling. The problem is `green` is taking up the entire height of `red`. I tried to reduce `green`'s height with `display: inline` and `inline-block`, as well as `height`, and also `align-items` and `align-content` on the parent, none of which worked.

**Is this possible with flexbox without resorting to CSS grid?**

Note: unfortunately, I cannot group `green` and `blue` because I must have `red` in between on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to even suggest this (because floats are evil) but you could do it via `float: left`. Flowing content around an element is fundamentally what float is for.

(I've removed the media query here to simplify viewing it in SO's tiny snippet frame.)

```css
#red { background: red; height: 500px }
#green { background: green; height: 200px }
#blue { background: blue; height: 100px }

/* desktop */
.container: { display: block; }
.container > * { float: left; }
#red { width: 33.33333% }
#green, #blue { width: 66.66666% }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="red">red</div>
  <div id="green">green</div>
  <div id="blue">blue</div>
</div>
```

Unless you want to start positioning things:

```css
#red { background: red; height: 500px }
#green { background: green; height: 200px }
#blue { background: blue; height: 100px }

/* desktop */
.container: { position: relative; padding-left: 33.3333%; }
#red { width: 33.33333%; position: absolute; }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="red">red</div>
  <div id="green">green</div>
  <div id="blue">blue</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, might have to resort to floats if there isn't an alternative.

Comment: Flex won't do this, and you explicitly said you don't want grid, so… I think float is the only remaining option unless you want to start positioning things. (You could position #red absolutely and then use left padding on the container to push #green and #blue to the right, but that's… suboptimal.)

Comment: Added another snippet using the position/padding idea in the comment above.

Comment: I voted this up, then removed my upvote because I disagree that floats are evil. They are very useful.